# Binding and Unbinding Backbone Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, kendo-ui

My Backbone view has a event Popout which when clicked creates a new View and open that view inside a Kendo Window. What i want is when i click on button, my events inside this view gets unbind and i can use my new view inside Kendo Window.
Next when i close Kendo Window, i want my events to rebind. However i am getting a error on this.

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'delegateEvents'
How can i rebind my events on close function of Kendo window?

```
popout: function(){
                this.stopListening();
                  //this.delegateEvents();
                  this.undelegateEvents();              
                var model = this.model;
                var popOutModuleView = new PopOutModuleView({model:model});
                lightRegion.show(popOutModuleView);
                Backbone.trigger("popout");
                event.preventDefault();
                var a = $('#lightbox').kendoWindow({
                    actions: ["Maximize", "Close"],
                    title: name,
                    width: "90%",
                        height: "90%",
                        resizable: true,
                    close: function(e){
                        popOutModuleView.remove();
                        lightRegion.close();
                        this.delegateEvents();                  
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this" does not refer to the Backbone.View, hence delegateEvents() is unknown. You'll have to bind this to the close function or make this available in the scope of the close function.

```
popout: function() {
    var _this = this;
    // CODE
    var a = $('#lightbox').kendoWindow({
        // CODE
        close: function() {
             _this.delegateEvents();
        }
    });
}
```